How do I place a button in an element of the Unity Editor array?
Hello everyone I am trying to place the button in my AnimationData, which has a custom PropertyDrawer, so that later in the AnimatedObject object, which has a list of such AnimationData, it is displayed correctly. But now she appears like this
Interface
The code in which I create the button:
private float DrawPositionsFields(SerializedProperty property, float x, float currentY, float width)
{
    float lineHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    float spacing = EditorGUIUtility.standardVerticalSpacing;

    Rect startPositionRect = new Rect(x, currentY, width, lineHeight);
    Rect endPositionRect = new Rect(x, currentY + lineHeight + spacing, width, lineHeight);

    SerializedProperty startPositionProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative(StartPositionField);
    SerializedProperty endPositionProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative(EndPositionField);

    startPositionProperty.vector3Value = EditorGUI.Vector3Field(startPositionRect, StartPositionFieldLabel, startPositionProperty.vector3Value);
    endPositionProperty.vector3Value = EditorGUI.Vector3Field(endPositionRect, EndPositionFieldLabel, endPositionProperty.vector3Value);

    currentY += 2 * (lineHeight + spacing);

    Rect buttonRect = new Rect(x, currentY, width, lineHeight);  // Используем ширину поля
    if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Edit"))
    {
        // Логика для кнопки
        var targetObject = property.serializedObject.targetObject;

        if (targetObject is AnimatedObject animatedObject)
        {
            int index = GetIndex(property.propertyPath);
            if (index >= 0 && index < animatedObject.Animations.Count)
            {
                AnimationData data = animatedObject.Animations[index];

                data?.OnEditing?.Invoke(data);
                Debug.Log("OnEditing invoked");
            }
        }
    }

    return currentY + (lineHeight + spacing);
}

Code from my custom AnimatedObject inspector
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(AnimatedObject))]
public class AnimatedObjectEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        SerializedProperty animationsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("_animations");

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(animationsProperty, new GUIContent("Animations"), true);
        DrawStopEditButton();
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private static void DrawStopEditButton()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Stop edit"))
        {

        }
    }
}

I want to keep the standard view of the list, but at the same time add a button to it. When I don't redraw the inspector, everything is displayed correctly, but I need a Stop edit button in it and there are such difficulties when adding it. Is there any way to fix this?
